# How to link_to tag names from tag_cloud?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tags, link-to, tag-cloud

```
  <% tag_cloud(@tags, %w(css1 css2 css3 css4)) do |tag, css_class| %>
    <%= link_to tag.name.titleize, tag_path(tag), :class => css_class %>
  <% end %>
```

If a user then clicks on one of the tags from the `tag_cloud` he is taken to: http://0.0.0.0:3000/tags/1, which is then blank.

Whereas if the user goes to a show page and clicks on one of the tags there `<%= raw @habit.tag_list.map { |t| link_to t.titleize, tag_path(t), class: 'label label-primary' } %>` he is taken to:
http://0.0.0.0:3000/tags/morning%20routine, which will list out all the instances of *morning routine* from any of the models.

**routes.rb**

```
get 'tags/:tag', to: 'pages#home', as: :tag
```

The tag_cloud is a multi model cloud so simply switching out `@tags` with `@habit` doesn't work.

Please let me know if you need further code or explanation :-] Keep the dream alive!

Comment: What are you trying to do by that raw statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! Took me awhile to figure out it only required a slight change:

```
  <% tag_cloud(@tags, %w(css1 css2 css3 css4)) do |tag, css_class| %>
    <%= link_to tag.name.titleize, tag_path(tag.name), :class => css_class %>
  <% end %>
```